# What is a NOT encapsulated List structure

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

My prof is talking about: 
„Solve a task about a list with loops over a not encapsulated list structure.“

What does he mean with this? ArrayLists? Arrays? LinkedLists? Can you exclude some lists structures/ types?

Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Perhaps it might be more clear if you have some details of the task.

Comment: Sorry these are my only information about the upcoming task :(

Comment: You need to provide more details and context to the question. *„Solve a task about a list with loops over a not encapsulated list structure.“* could mean many things.

Comment: Swap "with" with "which" and it makes a little more sense.  Although even then the sentence doesn't make total sense.  I think he just means you have a list value available to some other class which itself does the looping over that list.  i.e. The thing that does the looping does not encapsulate the list.  No.. I just read it again and it definitely doesn't make any sense at all :)  idk how he's a prof.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone here can answer your question unless your professor is on Stack Overflow and happens to run across your query. When your assignment is unclear, it's best to ask the instructor. You pay fees for a reason. It probably means an array or arraylist since the there's no intermediary layer, like a node, which hides the actual data in a linked list.

Comment: @MarsAtomic so because the list is not encapsulated excludes the opportunity to be a LinkedList, is that right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... real life intrudes. An encapsulated data structure is one which relies on one structure enclosing another structure. The enclosed structure is what holds data directly, and no mechanism outside of the enclosing structure can access the enclosed structure itself (only the data). A "not enclosed" structure *should* be a structure without the enclosed structure, but "not enclosed" is not a term that is typically used, so again, you are strongly advised to talk to your instructor and get value for your tuition.